# Mysql LOAD DATA INFILE performance, Windows vs Unix

Tags: mysql, performance, load-data-infile, multiplatform

I have created a benchmark of multiple `LOAD DATA` operations inserting millions of records into different tables.

i have surprised when i discovered that on windows my Benchmark finished after 1.15 hours, vs Unix where it finished after 1.45 hours.

Then i have created different benchmark for read operations which involves full table scanning using single time index (my measurement has a time value which is non unique).

For the second benchmark i received 5 times better results on Unix vs Windows.

What may be the reason for this? (I have only MyISAM tables)